# Regular expression in python - help needed

Tags: python, regex

Like many other people posting questions here, I recently started programming in Python.
I'm faced with a problem trying to define the regular expression to extract a variable name (I have a list of variable names saved in the list) from a string.
I am parsing part of the code which I take line by line from a file.
I make a list of variables,:

```
>>> variable_list = ['var1', 'var2', 'var4_more', 'var3', 'var1_more']
```

What I want to do is to define `re.compile` with something that won't say that it found two `var1`; I want to make an exact match. According to the example above, `var` should match nothing, `var1` should match only the first element of the list.

I presume that the answer may be combining regex with negation of other regex, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.

OK, I have noticed that I missed one important thing. Variable list is gathered from a string, so it's possible to have a space before the var name, or sign after.
More accurate variable_list would be something like

```
>>> variable_list = [' var1;', 'var1 ;', 'var1)', 'var1_more']
```

In this case it should recognize first 3, but not the last one as a var1.

Comment: More code and/or explanation would be useful. It's unclear what you mean by "extract a variable name". Do you want to create a separate regex for each variable knowing the variable name in advance, or do you want a re that matches any variable name? Can there be other stuff in these strings (eg: are they expressions) or are they just variable names that you want to check for validity?

Comment: I would like to do something like making the re.compile("(someregex)%s(someregex)", variable) where variable should be one from the list of known variables like known_variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var1_more'] with for variable in known_variables:

Comment: _Please_ format your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex with `^` and `$`, unless I'm not understanding you properly:

```
>>> mylist = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3_something', 'var1_text', 'var1var1']
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'^var1$')
>>> matches = [item for item in mylist if r.match(item)]
>>> print matches
['var1']
```

So `^var1$` will match exactly `var1`, but not `var1_text` or `var1var1`. Is that what you're after?

---

I suppose one way to handle your edit would be with `^\W*var1\W*$` (where `var1` is the variable name you want). The `\W` shorthand [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matches anything that is not in the `\w` class, and `\w` in Python is basically alphanumeric characters plus the underscore. The `*` means that this may be matched zero or more times. This results in:

```
variable_list = [' var1;', 'var1 ;', 'var1)', 'var1_more']
>>> r = re.compile(r'^\W*var1\W*$')
>>> matches = [item for item in variable_list if r.match(item)]
>>> print matches
[' var1;', 'var1 ;', 'var1)']
```

If you want the name of the variable without the extraneous stuff then you can capture it and extract the first capture group. Something like this, maybe (probably a bit inefficient since the regex runs twice on matched items):

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'^\W*(var1)\W*$')
>>> matches = [r.match(item).group(1) for item in variable_list if r.match(item)]
>>> print matches
['var1', 'var1', 'var1']
```

Comment: I have edited the question a bit, but so far, this is doing the job I need it to do, for the question that I have asked at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to learn about regular expressions, then maybe this is a useful puzzle, but if you want to see whether a certain word is in a list of words why not this:

```
>>> 'var1' in mylist
True
>>> 'var1 ' in mylist
False
```

Comment: The problem with this would be that I made a list from a file and I am not sure about the format of those lines. In your example, both 'var1' and 'var1 ' should be true, according what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Not to expand too much more on the regex match, but you might consider using the 'filter()' builtin:

```
filter(function, iterable)
```

So, using one of the regex's suggested by @eldarerathis:

```
>>> mylist = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3_something', 'var1_text', 'var1var1']
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'^var1$')

>>> matches = filter(r.match, mylist)
['var1']
```

Or using your own match function:

```
>>> def matcher(value):
>>>     ... match statement ...

>>> filter(matcher, mylist)
['var1']
```

Or negate the regex earlier with a lambda:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: not r.match(x), mylist)
['var2', 'var3_something', 'var1_text', 'var1var1']
```